# Complex python packaging with extension

Tags: python, c++, swig, packaging

I'm currently symplifying my packaging process.

I have a large open source library in C++ that normally designed to be installed in the system, but I want it to be installed locally in the python virtualenv like this

```
cd /path/to/mycpplibrary
sh ./autogen.sh
./configure –prefix=/home/user/virtualenvs/myvirtualenv (absolute path needed here)
make
make install
```

Theses commands compile and send the .so file to the folder `/home/user/virtualenvs/myvirtualenv`

Now I have swig package that uses this library. These commands generate the wrapped.cpp file

```
cd /path/to/swig-package
workon myvirtualenv
python setup.py wrap
```

And now it's time to compile it but it links to the .so file created previously

```
LD_RUN_PATH=/home/user/virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/ python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

I need to specify `LD_RUN_PATH=/home/user/virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/` for the build process to find the .so file.

This is the installation process that seems to be complex. I just don't think putting all the command line into a .sh file is a good solution. How can I package my swig-package that contains the `library.so` file and the `wrapped.so` file in one egg or wheel ?
Thanks

Comment: Usually the whole installation is done by the setup.py file. Why do you do things outside of it? I am a bit confused because I do not see what I would expect and do not understand the reasoning behind it.

Comment: Well, what you means is that all the c++ code of the library needs to be compiled inside the package `swig-package` ? I've thgouth about that but the configuration and makefile are complex, In that case I need to rewrite all the make files in setup.py and it's a lot of work. Do you have any idea ?